# Job hanging in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, jobs, worker

I am using `meteor-job-collection` and has defined a worker

```
var workers = Job.processJobs( 'jobQueue', 'insertItems',
  function ( job, cb ) {
    // iterate
    job.data.forEach( function ( item ) {
      // insert
    } );

    // when done successfully
    job.done();

    // invoke the callback when work on this job has finished
    return cb();
  }
);
```

It seems that my server is hanging until the job has been processed. Have I done something wrong? Should I enclose it in `wrapAsync` or `Tracker.autorun` or something?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs you should probably use `options.concurrency` to increase amount of concurrent job that can be processed at one time.
See screenshot of documentation of [meteor-job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection):

[image: docs]

Comment: Thanks but it is hanging even though I only have 1 running job, so I don't think setting the concurrency will affect anything in my situation. Even when I'm subscribing to the JobCollection, it takes unnaturally long (isn't it just a simple collection?)

Comment: You can wrap worker into Meteor.wrapAsync, then it should not block any more, because it will run in other Fiber

Comment: But the doc says that it will asynchronously call the worker function whenever jobs become available, so doesn't it already do this?